# PHP PDO MySQL parsing SQL query results efficiently

Tags: php, mysql, parsing, pdo

I am using PHP PDOs to parse the results I am receiving from MySQL queries against a database. I am now running into an issue with running out of allocated memory. Any suggestions on how to improve the efficiency of my code or another more efficient way to handle query results other than parsing PDOs? Thanks.

Here is my code (which will return whether or not a DB has referential integrity):

```
function generateDSN($host, $dbname)
{
    return 'mysql:host='. $host . ';dbname=' . $dbname; 
}


$dbName = $argv[2];
//Used for query construction

$dsn = generateDSN($argv[1], $argv[2]); 
//create DSN

$link = new PDO($dsn, "username", "password"); 
//Connect to the database
//PDO($dsn, username, password)

if ($link->connect_error) 
{
    die("Connection failed: " . $link->connect_error);
}
else
{
    echo "Connected successfully\n";    
}
//validate database connection


$query = "SELECT TABLE_CONSTRAINTS.TABLE_NAME, KEY_COLUMN_USAGE.COLUMN_NAME, KEY_COLUMN_USAGE.REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME, KEY_COLUMN_USAGE.REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS RIGHT OUTER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE ON INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS.CONSTRAINT_NAME = INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE.CONSTRAINT_NAME WHERE INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE.CONSTRAINT_NAME <> 'PRIMARY' AND INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY' AND INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS.TABLE_SCHEMA = '".$dbName."';"; 
//Create query to return list of tables with foreign keys 
/* Query return format: 
+--------------+------------------------+-----------------------+------------------------+
| TABLE_NAME   | COLUMN_NAME            | REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME | REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME |
+--------------+------------------------+-----------------------+------------------------+
*/

$result = $link->query($query);
//Get query results 

$x = 0; 
$tableA = [];
$tableB = [];
//Create arrays to hold data from FK queries

while($tables = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $test[] = $tables; 
    $assoc = $test[$x]; 
    //assign assoc[] the value of $query (will iterate through query table row by row)

    $tableName = $assoc['TABLE_NAME']; 
    $columnName = $assoc['COLUMN_NAME']; 
    $refTableName = $assoc['REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME'];
    $refColumnName = $assoc['REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME']; 
    //get data values for each column

    $fkQueryA = "SELECT DISTINCT " . $columnName . " FROM " . $dbName . "." . $tableName . " ORDER BY ".$columnName." ;"; 
    $fkQueryB = "SELECT DISTINCT " . $refColumnName . " FROM " . $dbName . "." . $refTableName . " ORDER BY ".$refColumnName." ;"; 
    //A -- Table with column that is the foreign key
    //B -- Table with column that the foreign key references

    $resultA = $link->query($fkQueryA);
    $resultB = $link->query($fkQueryB);
    //Get query results 

    while($var = $resultA->fetchColumn())
    {   
        $tableA[] = $var;
    }
    //Push query results to table


    while($vari = $resultB->fetchColumn())
    {
        $tableB[] = $vari; 
    }
    //Push query results to table

    $x++;
    //increment counter to move through $tables 
}

$resultCompAB = array_diff($tableA, $tableB); 
//return array with all values of A that are not in B


if(empty($resultCompAB))
{
    echo "Database ".$dbName." has referential integrity."; 
} 
else
{
    echo "Orphan Values in database ".$dbName.": \n"; 
    array_diff($tableB, $resultCompAB); 
}
//print the results
```

Comment: This might be a good question for 'Code Review': http://codereview.stackexchange.com You might get better answers there.

Comment: I'll post it there also. Thanks!

Comment: Please do not double-post and perhaps try to avoid too much horizontal scrolling? Line length! I'll have a look at your question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would fit better to Codereview.

Comment: I can see why you would run out of memory... :-) An operation on two whole table columns done in memory...

Comment: @eckes Being on-topic at Code Review and off-topic at Stack Overflow are not the same thing. Being on-topic at Code Review is not a close reason. If you feel this would be better on Code Review, then flag it for migration using a custom flag. If you feel this is off-topic for Stack Overflow for a reason defined in the help center, vote to close for that reason.

Comment: This is not a code review thing, it is a engineering issue. That comparison should not be done at php it can all be accomplished with a Query. With some joins he could get the orphans rows.

Comment: @DanielAranda You might be surprised at how much the questions and answers at [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) actually cover.

Comment: [Cross-posted](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/84571/9357) on Code Review.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the array_diff and storing GIGANT php arrays, you should get it with a Query.

This query, will give you values of A that are not in B:

```
$tableName = $assoc['TABLE_NAME']; 
$columnName = $assoc['COLUMN_NAME']; 
$refTableName = $assoc['REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME'];
$refColumnName = $assoc['REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME']; 


$sql = "SELECT * FROM {$tableName} LEFT JOIN {$refTableName}
ON {$tableName}.{$columnName} = {$refTableName}.{$refColumnName}
WHERE {$refTableName}.{$refColumnName} IS NULL
";
```